# Sorting Data by MMDDYY

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a spreadsheet filled will data by column it goes . Date , purchased from , cateogories , price , GST....
I need to organize all data transactions by MMDDYY , I have tried custom sorting and it still seems to sort alphabetically . Boss wont help as I'm sure ive done this before but ive tried several different steps and seem to keep getting stuck , cant seem to find the correct steps. Need this done ASAP ... Excel 2013 is what I am using. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If the data are formatted as dates, rather than strings, then normal sorting rules should apply.

Comment: I'm very new to using excel. I am currently taking a computer applications course. So the terminology isn't quite there yet for me . I'm quite unsure how I am to organize my data by MMDDYY but also having the values move correctly. I am sorry I probably make no sense. I just cant send out the spreadsheet with everything all unorganized .. it looks hideous

Comment: Just right-click on the column header (eg `A`), select Format Cells, click on Date and enter the custom format `MMDDYY`. (I don't have an up-to-date version of Excel, so I have tested with LibreOffice, which means that some of the dialogues may differ slightly.)

Comment: Alright ! So I am in my Format Cell Dialogue window (sorry for my terrible terminology) . Clicked on date but there is no option to enter a custom format. When I choose MMDDYY nothing in changes. Also wont this only sort my dates in the one column and not all the coinciding information? Thank you for your help

Comment: If Excel is sorting alphabetically, that seems to imply the dates are entered as Apr, May, Jun rather than 04, 05, 06. And it also seems to imply that the cells are formatted as string rather than date. As @AFH says, the cells need to be formatted as date for Excel to sort them properly. Do you want a date format of MMDDYY or MM/DD/YY? Custom format is its own format; it's not in Date format.

Comment: I must be doing something very wrong. when I select my column which contains my dates( Apr, May , Jun..) and format the cells to 04-01-18 for example . It still sorts alphabetically . Do I need to retype my dates . Thank you for baring with me

Comment: If your `Date` column only has month values, then they are not actually dates.

Comment: I suggest you read over this Microsoft page on [working with Dates and Time in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel).

Comment: Okay. So my dates look like this . Eg. April 10th 2018 . I have formatted the cells to mm-dd-yy . tried selecting all data and can not get it to stop sorting alphabetically. I have emailed my teacher , my boss , read my text book and I can not figure this out. Thank you so much for all your time and consideration . I will read the working with date and time in excel document and hopefully figure it out :(

Comment: How am I suppose to sort my current data. I don't want to create a new column and have the dates sorted seperately I need to sort all the information as all whole.

Comment: My column with the transaction date is being recognized as a date (MM-DD-YY)... when I highlight all my columns (headersincluded) and custom sort " transaction date(defined name), values , custom list (January , February , March..) and it is still sorting incorrectly

Comment: Just to be sure, if you take one of your dates and format it as `General`, what do you get? Does it stay as the date, or change to a long seemingly random number?

Comment: Yes if I change it to General it stays as a date and does not change to a number. I have also tried highlighting all my columns excluding my purchased from category and am unable to sort because excel does not recognize this as a proper range.

Comment: Yep, I thought so. You will need to re-enter all your date data as actual dates. See my answer below.

Comment: @BillDOe - I think that the questioner meant lexicographically for `MMDDYY` dates, rather than alphabetically, though neither term is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it seems that you have entered your dates as text data, instead of date data.

As described on the Microsoft Support page [How to work with Dates and Time in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214094/how-to-use-dates-and-times-in-excel), Dates are handle by Excel as increasing integers, starting at 1, which equates to 01/01/1900. Each day adds 1 to the value:

```
Integer |  Short Date
--------+------------
  1     |   1/01/1900
  2     |   2/01/1900
  3     |   3/01/1900
  4     |   4/01/1900
  5     |   5/01/1900
  6     |   6/01/1900
  7     |   7/01/1900
  367   |   1/01/1901
```

Excel handles dates in this way so that multiple types of formatting can be applied to the field, without the underlying date data being lost. For example:

`1 = 1/01/1900 = Sunday, 1 January 1900 = 1900-01-01`

If your date data is not stored as an integer, then Excel will not recognise it as such, no matter how you format it.

As good practice, you should enter all date data as simply as possible. As I live in a country that uses `dd/mm/yyyy` as our standard format, I would enter today's date at `22/02/2018`, then choose a `Short Date`, `Long Date`, or a `Custom` format to present this data in any way that is required.

Once you have proper Date data, you can apply a custom format such as `mmmm-dd-yyyy` to get results like `August-15-2018`. You will also then be able to sort by Oldest/Newest:

[image: Screenshot Example of sorting Oldest/Newest]

Comment: I have had to go out for a couple of hours, so I missed most of the discussion. A couple of points arise: (1) it is unnecessary to re-enter the dates -  next to the date (say `A`) insert a work column (`B`, formatted as `MMDDYY` date), with `B1` set to `=DATE(MID(A1,5,2),MID(A1,1,2),MID(A1,3,2))`, then copy it and paste down the rest of column `B`, which will give you the dates in the correct date format, then hide the text dates (column `A`); (2) early versions of Excel treated 1900 as a leap year (check day 60) - LibreOffice gets it correct, so day 1 is 31 Dec 1899.